# How to add listener to Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

here is my code:

```
function initLocations() {

    var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
          document.getElementById('pac-input'));


    var options = {
          componentRestrictions: {country: "be"},
         };
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        var thisplace = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (thisplace.address_components[4].long_name != null) {
            console.log(thisplace.address_components[4].long_name);
        }
    });
}
```

I am looking to make a lister, when I click to the autocomplete suggestions, that redirect me in an URL generated from the address...

So, when I search for Bruxelles, it shw me this:
Bruxelles, 1000, Belgium

**and when I click on it, I need  to redirect me here**:

```
/travel-bruxelles-1000
```

The city must be slugged.

How can I make this?

PS:
I need to slug the city name, ex:

```
New York, 60000

domain.com/travel-new-york-6000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a way for redirect the page you can use 
`window.location.replace`

for getting the posta code you should try this way

```
  for  (var i=0;  i < thisplace.address_components.length; i++ ) {
    if (thisplace.address_components[i].types  == 'posta_code') {
        myPostalCode = .thisplace.address_components[i].long_name;
    };
  }

myArray = thisplace.address_components[4].long_name.split(",");
cityName  = myArray[0].replace(/ /g, "-"); 
myPage = "/travel-" + cityName +"-" + myPostalCode; 

window.location.replace(myPage);
```

Comment: The question is, how do you generate the "myPage" variable from the google.maps.places.Autocomplete

Comment: In thisplace.address_components[4].long_name = you get always the NameCity, number, country ? and the location is always /travel-city-number ?

Comment: I have slightly updated the answer.. i hope this is useful

Comment: It sounds correct, and what about the multiple words city name? How can I replace the space with - ? (slug)

Comment: Show me a sample.. update the question with a sample of the city name and the aspected result..

Comment: Thank you scaisEdge, you're helping me to make the javascript part but the problem is still here... I don't know how to get properly the postal code from the Google map API... It depends the request sometime it works sometime not :(

Comment: Well i have update the answer with the way for manage the postal code .. anyway this seems not proper like you posted the original question.. normally in S.O. if   you post a question and get a right answer is fair mark it  as accepted and is if useful as useful too.

Comment: Of course, when the answer is correct I'will accept it. This is working for majority of address but not all of them, is it normal? Look here an official example (search for this on Bruxelles, Rue Ledeganck): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform